# Setting a hardcoded value on an Elastic document with Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to learn Painless so that I could use it while trying to enrich and manipulate incoming documents. However, every way I've seen for accessing the document just results in errors.
Having input this in the Painless Lab in Kibana, these are the errors I'm getting:

```
def paths = new String[3];
paths[0]= '.com';
paths[1] = 'bar.com';
paths[2] = 'foo.bar.com';
doc['my_field'] = paths;  // does not work: '[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues'
ctx.my_field = paths;  // does not compile: 'cannot resolve symbol [ctx.my_field]'
return doc['my_field'] == 'field_value';  // does not work: 'No field found for [my_field] in mapping'
```

`doc['my_field'] == 'field_value'` complains despite the field being present in the test document, though `doc.containsKey('my_field')` does return `false`.

How should I actually be accessing and manipulating the incoming document? I'm using ElasticSearch 7.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) with [set processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/set-processor.html) for adding hardcode value to incoming document.

```json
{
  "description" : "sets the value of count to 1",
  "set": {
    "field": "count",
    "value": 1
  }
}
```

There are very specific [context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-shared.html#painless-api-reference-shared) available for painless API. you are using `String[]` which may be causing issue so you need to use either `Arrays` or `ArraysList`. you can check example of painless lab [here](https://alexmarquardt.com/2020/11/09/using-kibanas-painless-lab-beta-to-test-an-ingest-processor-script/).

Below is script i have tried in painless lab and it is working as expcted:

```
def ctx = params.ctx;
ArrayList paths = new ArrayList();
paths.add('.com');
paths.add('bar.com');
paths.add('foo.bar.com');
ctx['my_field'] = paths;
return ctx
```

[image]

Add below in parameters tab, i missed to add this in answer. this required because in actual implmentation you will get value from context and update context.

```json
{
  "ctx":{
    "my_field":["test"]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I paste that in Painless Lab, I get 'Unhandled Exception null_pointer_exception', apparently somehow at `"paths.add('foo.bar.com');\n"`. What do you have under the context tab? Or maybe there is a difference between versions that I forgot to mention? I'm using Elastic 7.12. Also, I'm unsure what I could do with your link to the plain list in the Elastic documentation.

Comment: Okay, that helps. But somehow, my Painless Lab only accepts returns of boolean values, so no `return ctx` or (as in the blog post you linked to) `return params`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes because you have selected `filter` from context tab. just change it to `basic` and it will work.